# How to Convert Startup Code from asp.net core 2.1 to Startup Code asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to upgrate my project from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 3.1, I have changed the SDK to 3.1 like the below code, but I did not know what to change in my startup code as per need of startup code 3.1

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now I want to update my startup Code from asp.net core 2.1 to asp.net core 3.1 Please modify the below startup code  as per the need of asp.net core 3.1

Here is my Startup Code Version asp.net Core 2.1

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBconnection");
        services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(10,00,00);
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });
        
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
        {
            option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
        });
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
               template: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Package Manger Reference Code asp.net core 2.1 need to update to asp.net core 3.1

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt-Core" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.97.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU" Version="7.8.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.aspnetcore.app" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.14">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.2.7" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is my UserProfile Controller Code, by default from Startup EndpointRouting user will come to this page, if a user is not login it will redirect to the login page

```
 [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? passIsChanged = null) // userId
    {
        if (passIsChanged != null)
        {
            ViewBag.isSuccessed = passIsChanged;
        }
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        var user = _context.UserAccountTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins");
        }
            userprofile = new UserProfile
            {
                UserId = user.UserId,
                Name = users.FirstName,
            };


        return await Task.FromResult(View(userprofile));
    }
```

Here is My Login Controller code, if user is not login it return a new login model, if user is login it will check its password and user name then and validate it,

```
  public LoginsController(HoshmandDBContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => View(new Login()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin([FromForm] Login currentUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = currentUser.RememberMe,
                AllowRefresh = false,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(10)
            };

            UserAccountTb user = _context.UserAccountTbs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(currentUser.UserName));
            if (user == null)
            {
                TempData["UserLoginFailed"] = "Login Failed: Please Enter Correct Credential";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                // validate the password and login if not validate 
                show a message that enter correct password 
            }
```

Comment: You should be asking about .NET 6. .NET Core 3.1 reaches End Of Life in 2 weeks. The Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024

Comment: The migration docs describe the changes needed to migrate [from .NET Core 2 to .NET Core 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [.NET Core 3 to .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). The double jump requires quite a lot of changes though and it's probably better to create a new .NET 6 MVC or Web API project and copy the code. A lot of the boilerplate that was in `Startup.cs` is now taken care through conventions

Comment: The [.NET (Core) Lifecycle page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) shows that .NET Core 3.1 reaches EOL in December 13, 2022. That's less than 2 weeks from now. You can expect library and component authors to drop support for it very quickly

Comment: Is your authentication code hand-rolled or a customization of ASP.NET Core Identity? Customizing auth pages changes from 2 to 3 to 6 quite a lot. You can now scaffold the Identity pages and modify them any way you want. You don't have to write everything from scratch if you want to change the UI

Comment: Yes I have written user Identify from screech

Comment: I suspect that's no longer needed. In any case even if you finish migration before December 13, you'll have to start again. It's better to migrate to .NET 6 directly and check whether you can use ASP.NET Identity for the login code

Comment: Looking at that BCrypt reference, I suspect you used custom authentication because you wanted a "safer" crypto algorithm. That package had no new release since 2017 though. Your password storage is less secure than using ASP.NET Identity already. In ASP.NET Core Identity 3 and later you can configure hashing parameters like the iterations and switch from the default 10K hash iterations to eg 300K. You can also customize the hashing algorithm.

Comment: Through some googling I found [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/aspnet-identity/improving-the-aspnet-core-identity-password-hasher#:~:text=The%20default%20ASP.NET%20Core,bit%20subkey%2C%20and%2010%2C000%20iterations.) that shows how to use Blowfish as the Identity hashing algorithm. I'm not endorsing it (it's just the first one I found) but it shows you *can* use Blowfish. [The hasher code is simple](https://github.com/scottbrady91/ScottBrady91.AspNetCore.Identity.BCryptPasswordHasher/blob/master/src/ScottBrady91.AspNetCore.Identity.BCryptPasswordHasher/BCryptPasswordHasher.cs) ...

Comment: ... so you can modify it to use a supported BCrypt package

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change SDK in .csproj file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

and remove this line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Second, update the Nuget package you added to 3.1
corresponding version:
[image]

Then, you can change your Startup.cs:

1. `options.Cookie.Expiration` is not supported in .net 3.1, you need to use `options.ExpireTimeSpan` to replace it.
2. Change `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)`; to `services.AddMvc();`.
3. The use of `app.UseMvc();` to define endpoints will no longer be supported in .net 3.1. You need to use `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseEndpoints();`.

In the end, your Startup.cs should look like this:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBconnection");
            services.AddDbContext<HoshmandDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Logins/UserLogin/";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);
            });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
            {
                option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(540);
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HasAccess", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new HasAccessRequirment()));
            });
            services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();
            services.AddTransient<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => {
                endpoint.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=UserProfiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

In addition, I added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the `Index` method of `UserProfilesController` to verify redirection:

```
public class UserProfilesController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

LoginsController:

```
public class LoginsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Then run the project:
[image]

Right click on your project and select "Manage NuGet Packages", you can see the references of all your packages. Then select the corresponding package and update to the appropriate version:
[image]

Comment: Dear Chen, I have included my package manger code in my question, please have look at that and guide me on how to update the version of each to asp.net core 3.1 ,Package Manger Reference Code asp.net core 2.1 need to update to asp.net core 3.1 
@Chen

Comment: I have change my startup code as you mentioned, but again I got this error,
`InvalidOperationException: The view 'UserLogin' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/UserLogin.cshtml` 

My UserLogin View exists in this directory  /Views/Logins/UserLogin.cshtml, 
@Chen

Comment: Hi, @Hedayat Hoshmand, Have you tried changing to the default HomeController to see if you can successfully redirect? For example:"/Home/Index".

Comment: Hi Dear @Chen, yes I have to changed it to Home/Index, but again same error,  
`[Authorize(policy: "HasAccess")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public HomeController(HoshmandDBContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IMvcControllerDiscovery mvcControllerDiscovery) : base(context)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            _mvcControllerDiscovery = mvcControllerDiscovery;
        }
        public IActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)
        {return View();}`

Comment: I have included my login controller and user profile controller to my question, pleas have a look @Chen

Comment: Can `return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins");` in UserProfileController be executed successfully? @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: Yes from user profile , return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Logins"); to Login Page Successfully @Chen

Comment: from User Profile Redirect to Logins, here 
`public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin()
 { return await Task.Run(() => View(new Login()));}`

Comment: I have created a new EmptyView in this dirctory /Views/Logins/EmptyView and returned it in  LoginController like below, 

`public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin() {return await Task.FromResult(View("EmptyView"));} `

Again this error occur The view 'EmptyView' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Logins/EmptyView.cshtml @Chen

Comment: Weird, you can redirect from a controller method and the url is the same, it shouldn't be such a problem.

Comment: I have debugged the code and returned the home view user profile view, and another view, for all views, the error occurred that the view is not found, so I think the main problem is in my startup in cookies or somewhere else after I have changed my startup code from asp.net 2.1 to asp.net 3.1 this error happen, now my project return no view, for all view error show that view not found @Chen

Comment: Try to annotate `Authorization Policy` and `services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();` to verify with the most concise code to see if it can succeed. And I noticed that you are not using `app.UseAuthorization();` middleware. @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: I have disabled and commented on this line of code but again the same error
`//services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasAccessHandler>();`

Please can you check my PackgeManger Code, and how to change the version to asp.net core 3.1,  might be the issue is there @Chen

Comment: I updated my answer about change the version of NuGet Pacages. @Hedayat Hoshmand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250039/discussion-between-hedayat-hoshmand-and-chen).